# UICollectionView incorrect width in cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need 2 cells for each row.

With exactly the middle of the controller width.

In iPhone 5 case. The Screen width is `320` and each row will be `160`.

```
self.view.frame.size.width => 320.0
midleWidth => 160.0
```

But when  the CollectionView is drawed the cell are separated, like the next image:

[image]

My CollectionView config is:

[image]

> When i put the `self.view.frame.size.width` as the width of cell, take all width of the screen as expected.

Comment: have set cell spacing in the code any where ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Try this Below Code

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(
        "Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let viewsDictionary = ["View1": collectionView]
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[View1]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[View1]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView : UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    let cellSize:CGSize = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.width / 2, self.bounds.height)
    return cellSize
}
```

Comment: Thanks for aswer, Works, but return a big warning for each cell, related with layout problems. `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints` and `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe1fbcc5890 UICollectionView:0x7fe1fc06de00.leading == UIView:0x7fe1fbcc49c0.leadingMargin - 20>` and `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe1fbd42870 H:|-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7fe1fc06de00]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fe1fbcc49c0 )>`

Comment: try to add this code - cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds
        cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]

Answer (score 1):

// use like this it will work for all devices

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize size;
    CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    double bWidth = (bounds.size.width/320)* 200 ; // 200 is your cell width which given in xib
    double bheight = (bWidth/320)* 250 // 250 is your cell height which given in xib;
    size = CGSizeMake(bWidth, bheight);

    return size;
}
```

Comment: this line `(bounds.size.width/320)* 200` always in iphone 5 is 200. -> `(320 / 320) * 200 = 200`. And 200 is not the middle of the screen. If change `200` by `bounds.size.width / 2` the same space between cells appear again

Comment: you need to give your cell width there, i give the sample values

Answer (score 1):

The above answer won't work for all devices try this

```
    - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                          layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
          sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            CGSize windowSize=[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].frame.size;

             return CGSizeMake(windowSize.width/2,heightOfCell);
        }
    - (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                   layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
return 0.0
}

    - (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                   layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but same result. Same space.

Comment: Thanks man, but not works. this 2 functions is the same that i added in my question in `My CollectionView config is:`.  likewise try, but nothing